# Cannot parse long value to date in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I have xml tag like as below:

```
<row number="3" cols="3">
..
   <col number="7">41973</col>
</row>
```

which 41973 describe the day 11/30/2014.
How I can parse value 41973 to date in xslt?

Best regards,

Comment: What are you using to execute your XSLT? Your best bet may be to use a custom function if your processor allows it.

Comment: "*41973 describe the day 11/30/2014.*" By what logic?

Comment: I parse an cell in excel file to xml and get the above value.
The format of cell is date and it shows 11/30/2014.

Comment: @TrungTrịnh Are you going to answer my question?

Comment: @michael.hor257k That's how Excel stores dates. It's the number of days since 1900-01-00.

Comment: Thanks all.
Before, I used java code but the begin day is different among java and exel. After than, I used your xslt template, the result is ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Convert Excel serial date number in the 1900 date system to ISO-8601 date (YYYY-MM-DD):

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:template name="excel-serial-number-to-date">
    <xsl:param name="excel-serial-number"/>
    <xsl:param name="JDN" select="$excel-serial-number + 2415019 + ($excel-serial-number &lt; 61)"/>
    <xsl:param name="f" select="$JDN + 1401 + floor((floor((4 * $JDN + 274277) div 146097) * 3) div 4) - 38"/>
    <xsl:param name="e" select="4*$f + 3"/>
    <xsl:param name="g" select="floor(($e mod 1461) div 4)"/>
    <xsl:param name="h" select="5*$g + 2"/>

    <xsl:param name="D" select="floor(($h mod 153) div 5 ) + 1"/>
    <xsl:param name="M" select="(floor($h div 153) + 2) mod 12 + 1"/>
    <xsl:param name="Y" select="floor($e div 1461) - 4716 + floor((14 - $M) div 12)"/>

    <xsl:param name="MM" select="format-number($M, '00')"/>
    <xsl:param name="DD" select="format-number($D, '00')"/>

    <xsl:value-of select="concat($Y, '-', $MM, '-', $DD)" />
</xsl:template>
```

Example of calling the template:

```
<output>
        <xsl:call-template name="excel-serial-number-to-date">
            <xsl:with-param name="excel-serial-number" select="41973" />
        </xsl:call-template>
</output>
```

Result:

```
<output>2014-11-30</output>
```

---

**Note**:
The result for Excel serial date numbers `60` and `61` will be the same: `1900-03-01`. That's because the date `1900-02-29` which Excel associates with serial number `60`  does not exist in the Gregorian calendar.

Comment: @TrungTrịnh Please accept this answer if it solved your problem. If it did not, point out what's still missing.